# How do i make the bots prefix not case sensitive on discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a discord bot that has the prefix "Arm " (Yes with the space) and i would like to make it not case sensitive so its less annoying to use.

I have tried the solutions in this thread ([Is there a way to make my prefix non case sensitive (Discord.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58979808/is-there-a-way-to-make-my-prefix-non-case-sensitive-discord-js)) but they didnt seem to work

This is a bit of my code

```
const config = require("./config.json");

client.on("message", async message => {

if(message.author.bot) return;
 
if(!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;
```

This is my config

```
{ 
  "token"  : "Token here",
  "prefix" : "Arm "
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```js
if(!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;
```

with

```js
if(message.content.slice(0, config.prefix.length).toLowerCase() !== config.prefix) return;
```

and change the prefix from `"Arm "` to `"arm "`.